# Define a cube and three intervals in Prolog

Tags: prolog, topology, clpq

I need to define a cube and three intervals Cx, Cy, and Cz as the projections of the cuboid on the x-, y-, and z-axes, respectively. I'm supposed to use the interval predicate `interval_dur`. The image on the link may more clear what i need indeed.

[Cuboid projections](http://imageshack.com/a/img571/7089/zou0.png)

The original question goes like this:

> We can define three-dimensional qualitative spatial relations between cuboids such as *inside* and *on top of* by considering the qualitative relations between their projections on each axis. Figure 1 shows cuboid `C` with interval projections on the x-, y-, and z-axes. (a)  Define a cuboid `C`. Define three intervals `Cx`, `Cy`, and `Cz` as the projections of the cuboid on the x-, y-, and z-axes, respectively. Use the interval predicate `interval_dur`.

Comment: It's a fairly terse problem description, but I think you'd want to define the cube in terms of three intervals, and each interval consists of two values. In prolog, you can have "nested terms", like `foo(bar(1,2),bar(3,4))`, etc. It sounds like `interval_dur` is supposed to be the name of the interval term, but it's not totally clear. Or was there a predicate `interval_dur` already given?

Comment: The original question like this;


We can dene three-dimensional qualitative spatial relations between cuboids such as inside and on top of by considering the qualitative relations
between their projections on each axis. Figure 1 shows cuboid c with
interval projections on the x-, y-, and z-axes.
(a) [5P] Dene a cuboid C. Dene three intervals Cx, Cy, and Cz as the
projections of the cuboid on the x-, y-, and z-axes, respectively. Use
the interval predicate interval_dur.

Comment: The only information i have is the question and the image which i posted on the question.

Thanks for your concern

Comment: it is still unclear whether you are already given that predicate "`interval_dur`", and what is it supposed to mean/do? What/how many arguments is it supposed to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the question: you need to create a predicate interval_dur(C, Cx, Cy, Cz) such that "cuboid" C and intervals Cx, Cy, Cz are related in a specified way.

"C" can be specified using three points, so the whole predicate could be something like this:

```
interval_dur(C, Cx, Cy, Cz) :-
    C = ((X1, Y1, Z1), (X2, Y2, _Z2), (_X3, _Y3, Z3)),
    Cx = (X1, X2),
    Cy = (Y1, Y2),
    Cz = (Z1, Z3).
```

This formulation assumes that points in C are in a specific order: the most close bottom left first, etc. This can be improved using sorting.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I got such a error - iUndefined procedure: interval_dur/4.

Comment: You should save the code to a file and then consult the file from Prolog before making queries.

Answer (score 0):

By sure this answer could be off topic, but since you tagged SWI-Prolog your question, I will show an extension that have been made available in version 7.1: [dicts](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=dicts).

```
:- module(cuboid, []).

M.cx() := Cx :- Cx is M.x2 - M.x1 .
M.cy() := Cy :- Cy is M.y2 - M.y1 .
M.cz() := Cz :- Cz is M.z2 - M.z1 .

M.volume() := V :- V is M.cx() * M.cy() * M.cz().

M.scale(F) := cuboid{x1:X1, x2:X2, y1:Y1, y2:Y2, z1:Z1, z2:Z2} :-
        maplist(mult(F, M), [x1,x2, y1,y2, z1,z2], [X1,X2, Y1,Y2, Z1,Z2]).

mult(F, M, A, V) :- V is M.A * F.
```

here is an example of use

```
1 ?- C = cuboid{x1:1, x2:2, y1:1, y2:2, z1:1, z2:2}, writeln(C.volume()).
1
C = cuboid{x1:1, x2:2, y1:1, y2:2, z1:1, z2:2}.

2 ?- S = $C.scale(3), Vs = S.volume().
S = cuboid{x1:3, x2:6, y1:3, y2:6, z1:3, z2:6},
Vs = 27.
```

I have little clue about `spatial relations` or `qualitative relations` you are looking for. I imagine that will be a set of spatial relations between two cuboids, like

```
intersect, is_on_top, is_at_left, etc...
```

Depending on the applicative domain you are supposed to handle, consider using a constraint library. library([clpr](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpqr)) for reals, library([clpq](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpqr)) for rationals, or library([clpfd](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd)) for integers.

This last one is more developed, and actively mantained.

Comment: +1 for using `dicts' which are a nice addition even though their implementation seems weak atm